# SilverStripe CMS interface is it possible to make the table editable?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

SilverStripe CMS interface you can make the table editable, such as add and remove rows, as well as edit text and information inside the cells. Is there any component that can help?

Just for example
[this is the result I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyKFK.gif)

**Thank you**

Comment: Here's a useful module for extending the grid field functionality https://github.com/symbiote/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions. According to the documentation there's a component which allows inline editing `GridFieldEditableColumns - allows inline editing of records`. I've not used that specific component myself so I can't give any details on how it works, but it can be worth to check it out.

Comment: @ConnyNyman this is the correct answer to this question (at least for inline editing).
kenlog: if you get stuck please share some code with us so we can help you on a specific problem. Just making the fields editable should be pretty staight forward, if you need e.g. specific dropdowns with given values it's a little bit more complicated. But only the first time ;)

Comment: You can add rows with the "add" button above (if your user has "canAdd" permission to this dataobject), you can delete or unlink rows automatically when your user has  "canDelete" permisions. Admin always has, other users might need the permissions. See also in the docs:
https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/forms/field_types/gridfield

Comment: **Many thanks** @ConnyNyman and wmk, i think "Grid Field Extensions Module" is the best solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer as it seem to have helped the questioner.

> Here's a useful module for extending the grid field functionality https://github.com/symbiote/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions. According to the documentation there's a component which allows inline editing GridFieldEditableColumns - allows inline editing of records. I've not used that specific component myself so I can't give any details on how it works, but it can be worth to check it out.